# CLR deployment from Visual studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, deployment, clr

i have a lot of stored procedures in SQL Database project and want to publish/deploy to Production environment. I changed let say 3 Stored procedures and want to deploy just one stored procedure. How can I do that because publish always deploys everything that changed.

Thanks

Comment: Well....as you noticed. When you deploy your code it deploys ALL of your code, not just some portion of it. If you want go down that slippery path you will have to deploy your updated procedure code manually.

Comment: Ok. But how to update only one stored procedure?

Comment: You can't using deploy. You have to script the change in a query window and run it.

Comment: Maybe some example on the Internet or similar. I have found examples but all change underlying assembly.

Comment: Again....you can't do this using deploy. It will deploy everything that changed as it should. If you don't want that you simply right click the procedure(s) you do want and click modify. This will generate a script for that procedure. You have to do this manually, there is no automated workaround here.

Comment: You cannot modify CLR stored procedure through MSSQL. I asked how to deploy manually without chnaging whole asembly